# Interaction between zero-width matchers and backreferences

Tags: regular-expression, pattern, match, undocumented-behaviour

Take a file with the following text as a workbench.

```
hello world hello world
```

With the cursor at the beginning of the line, here's how [`\1`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C1) interacts with [`\(…\)`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%28%5C%29), [`\@=`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3D), and [`\@!`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%21)

| # | regex | matched text | text matched by `\1` | why |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `\(world\).*\1` | `world hello world` | `world` | which is what `\(…\)` is matching |
| 2 | `\(world\)\@=.*\1` | `world hello world` | `world` | which is what `\(…\)` is matching even though `\@=` makes it zero-width |
| 3 | `\%(world\).*\1` | nothing (`E65: Illegal back reference`) | not valid | as `\%(…\)` forgets the match |
| 4 | `\%(world\)\@=.*\1` | nothing (`E65: Illegal back reference`) | not valid | as `\%(…\)` forgets the match |
| 5 | `\(world\)\@!.*\1` | the whole line? | any zero-width position, i.e. everywhere? |  |
| 6 | `\(world\)\@!.*` | the whole line | n.a. |  |
| 7 | `\(world\)\@!.*\1\1` | the whole line? | any zero-width position, i.e. everywhere? |  |
| 8 | `\(world\)\@!.*\1\1\1` | the whole line? | any zero-width position, i.e. everywhere? |  |

As it's clear from #5, I don't understand what `\1` is doing in `\(world\)\@!.*\1`:

- from #2, I would say that `\(world\)` matches `world` even if the `\@=` after it makes it consume no text,
- so I would have expected the same was true when applying `\@!`, but that appears not to be the case from #5
- and the difference is not that `\1` is invalid, as proved by #3 and #4
- #6 tells us that `\1` in #5 (and #7 and #8) is matching anywhere with zero width

Any idea?

The documentation doesn't seem to help.

Comment: In other language's flavor, use `(?=world).*\1`, this will report an error: `\1` references a non-existent or invalid subpattern. We can use `(?=(world)).*\1`, which is equivalent to `\(world\)\@=.*\1` in Vim. Following this line of thought, we can test `(?!(world)).*\1` in other flavor by https://regex101.com. We will find similar or strange results in other languages. So the issue you listed above is not only in Vim, this seems to be a common problem with all regex engines processing.